# Julia what does a nameless value in the function header mean?

Tags: julia

I often see something like the following in Julia:

```
convert(::Type{Point{Float64}}, ::Float64)
```

how does the `(::` work? And what is the terminology for this?

Comment: I just realized your second argument does not have a name either, which strikes me as a bit weird for a function header. Is it from an error message perhaps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your answer can be found in [the Julia documentation for defining conversions](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/conversion-and-promotion/#defining-new-conversions). To quote (with types switched to make it even more straightforward to read):

> The type of the first argument of this method is a [singleton
>   type](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/types/#man-singleton-types), `Type{Point{Float64}}`, the only instance of which is
>   `Point{Float64}`. Thus, this method is only invoked when the first
>   argument is the type value `Point{Float64}`. Notice the syntax used
>   for the first argument: the argument name is omitted prior to the `::`
>   symbol, and only the type is given. **This is the syntax in Julia for a
>   function argument whose type is specified but whose value is never
>   used in the function body.** In this example, since the type is a
>   singleton, there would never be any reason to use its value within the
>   body.

(Emphasis mine)

You will also encounter the `foo(::SomeType)` syntax in error messages, when trying to invoke a function with arguments of the wrong type (after all you can't show the argument names of a variant that does not exist). E.g:

```
julia> foo(x::Bool) = 3
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo(5)
ERROR: `foo` has no method matching foo(::Int64)
```